# How to access custom pipeline in BizTalk Server Administration Console

Tags: c#, biztalk

I created a custom receive pipeline, built and deployed it. I want to use it in my BizTalk Server application, but it doesn't show up on the "Receive pipeline" drop down list in Receive Location. Its added to the GAC and in the pipeline components directory. How do I get BizTalk Server to see it?

Comment: Did you restart the host instances after deploying it, and clicked refresh in the Admin Console?

Comment: yes, did that..

Answer (score 1):

I added the pipeline.dll to my orchestration project, and deployed it. Not sure how, but it showed up in the pipelines in BizTalk Server, this time.